# Magento 2.4, How to load multiple category data by array of category ids?

Tags: magento2, category, collection

In Magento 2.4, I need to load multiple category data. How to load multiple category data by array of category ids?

Answer (score 0):

I have not clear you question but as per my assume.I have make to array of category ids. Just i have use object manager.

```
$categoryCollection = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory')->create();
$categoryCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', [3, 4]);

foreach ($categoryCollection->getItems() as $category) {
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor $category */

    // get the category data
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($category->getData());
}



die("Helllo");
```

And see both category data

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like :

```
$categoryCollection = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory')->create();
$categoryCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => [3, 4]]);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your code. I will check and let you know.